# How to exclude mirror reflection of an object to avoid double counting in object detection

Tags: python, object-detection, yolo

I'm working with some YOLO models on test video to classify people in the frame. Naturally, whenever a mirror is present in the frame, an object detection Network will identify a person and all the instances of it's reflection, so if I wanted to count people in a room with two mirrors 1 person will count as 3.

Is there a feasible workaround for this? Also is it possible to avoid adding another CNN to the pipeline?

[Example image for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LX8yX.jpg)

Comment: Where in the frame will the mirror be? Can you share an example image?

Comment: Sure, see link in edit

Comment: It's doable if the mirrors will always be at the same position in the images. If the position and number of mirrors varies a lot, I'm afraid there is no practical way to do it

Comment: That’s the assumption, yes. The camera is fixed and the mirrors will stay in place from that cameras perspective